# mib2c - show all variable attributes

Tags: attributes, net-snmp, mib

I am very new to mib2c, and I need to list all attributes which belong to one variable.
I work with mib2c tool from NET-SNMP and there are configuration templates for generating the code.

There are variables with many attributes, look like:

```
$var.defval
$var.type
```

I would like to see all these attributes, in order to use them in the generated code.
I know, for mib2c attributes there is [man page](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/mib2c.conf.html), but there is not everything. (For example I know the attribute `$var.needlength` exists, and it is not mentioned in that man page).

I don't know how the `$var` is defined and fulfilled.

How can I list all attributes of `$var`?

Comment: I don't get it, if $var is a real Perl variable or not? If former, one can always use a Data::Dumper sledgehammer. )

Comment: mib2c is not Perl, it just looks a little bit like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can do this programmatically, given the constraints of the mib2c pseudo-Perl but I just looked in `/usr/bin/mib2c` (it's a script, not a compiled executable so you can easily examine the code) and found the following.

There are only four **undocumented** variables in the mib2c script:

- lastchange
- storagetype
- needlength
- enumrange

There are many more **documented** variables in the mib2c script:

- uc
- objectID
- commaoid
- oidlength
- subid
- module
- parent
- isscalar
- iscolumn
- children
- perltype
- type
- decl
- readable
- settable
- creatable
- noaccess
- accessible
- rowstatus
- hasdefval
- defval
- hashint
- hint
- ranges
- enums
- access
- status
- syntax
- reference
- description

That being said, I'm not sure what exactly you are hoping to find, so I'm not sure that this really answers your question.